# Java class files with $ symbol

Tags: java, class

I have a class with name StreamGo. It has 4 more class files with the same name like - StreamGo$1, StreamGo$2 etc. All these class files have different set of code. How do I merge them? And why does these class files get created with $1 and $2 etc?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those class files are automatically generated for *anonymous inner classes* defined inside `StreamGo.java`. For example, if you have something like this:

```
final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // ...
    }
};
```

then you'll have a `StreamGo$1.class` for the anonymous implementation of `Runnable` that you've defined here.

*Named* nested classes will do much the same, except that you'll get their names instead of the number part.

Answer (score 1):

These are compiler-generated classes for anonymous classes that you create in your class.

Since Java bytecode requires a separate `.class` file for each class, you cannot merge them.

You may want to put all of your `.class` files into a `.jar`.

Answer (score 1):

If there is an inner class in your java file, then the compiler will create a class file with name of Java file along with $. You cannot combine these class files. But if you are copying these class files, make sure you are copying all the class files starting with $ symbol! else it will not work